# Python rospy Script doesn't end running

Tags: ros, python, script, rospy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey there,

i already talked to some guys in #python irc channel. My aim was to close a while loop with ctrl-c so i used a try - exception statement. The problem is that the while loop doesnt really close. If i put a print "whatever" in the exception statement it doesnt get printed, though the code in the while loop doesnt get executed anymore. People said that my code itself seems correct. So i used the faulthandler to get deeper into that problem and it seems that it has smth to do with ROS. But im not into programming that deeply to understand what is going wrong here or maybe its just a simple mistake i make...

Anyways, here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import time
import sys

#Ueye Imports
import ids

#ROS Imports
import rospy
from sensor_msgs.msg import Image

#OpenCV Imports
import cv2
from cv_bridge import CvBridge, CvBridgeError

import faulthandler
import signal

faulthandler.enable()
faulthandler.register(signal.SIGUSR1)

# +++++++++++++++ ROS Node Einstellugen +++++++++++++++
# Diese Node agiert unter dem Namen "NeedleDetector"
rospy.init_node('VideoPublisher', anonymous=True)

# und published folgende Topics:
VideoRaw = rospy.Publisher('Kamera_Rohbild', Image, queue_size=10)
EdgesRaw = rospy.Publisher('Kamera_Kantenbild', Image, queue_size=10)
# ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

cam = cv2.VideoCapture('output.avi')

# ++++++++++++++++ Einstellungen Bildverarbeitung +++++++++++++++
#Einstellungen fuer den Gaussschen Weichzeichner
gaussian_blur_ksize = (5, 5)
gaussian_blur_sigmaX = 4

#Die Threshold Werte fuer den Canny Operator
threshold1 = 55
threshold2 = 75
# +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
br = CvBridge()


try:
    while cam.isOpened():

        # Naechstes Bild abfragen
        meta, frame = cam.read()

        # Anwendung des Gausschen Weichzeichners um das Rauschen etwas zu unterdruecken
        frame_gaus = cv2.GaussianBlur(frame, gaussian_blur_ksize, gaussian_blur_sigmaX)

        # ueberfuehren in ein Graustufen Bild fuer den Canny Algorithmus
        frame_gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame_gaus, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

        # ueberfuehren in das Kantenbild
        frame_edges = cv2.Canny(frame_gray, 55, 75)

        # umwandeln der Numpy Arrays in die ROS Nachricht
        frame_msg = br.cv2_to_imgmsg(frame, "rgb8")
        frame_msg_edges = br.cv2_to_imgmsg(frame_edges, "mono8")

        # Nachrichten veroeffentlichen
        VideoRaw.publish(frame_msg)
        EdgesRaw.publish(frame_msg_edges)

        time.sleep(0.1)

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print "1"
    rospy.is_shutdown()
    cam.close()
    print "2"
```

And here is what the faulthandler said:

```
Thread 0x00007f8f02b25700:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 358 in wait
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/impl/tcpros_pubsub.py", line 418 in _run
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 763 in run
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 810 in __bootstrap_inner
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 783 in __bootstrap
 
Thread 0x00007f8eea43b700:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 358 in wait
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/impl/tcpros_pubsub.py", line 418 in _run
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 763 in run
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 810 in __bootstrap_inner
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 783 in __bootstrap
 
Thread 0x00007f8ee9c3a700:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 358 in wait
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/impl/tcpros_pubsub.py", line 418 in _run
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 763 in run
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 810 in __bootstrap_inner
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 783 in __bootstrap
 
Thread 0x00007f8f02324700:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 224 in meth
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/impl/tcpros_base.py", line 650 in write_data
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/impl/tcpros_pubsub.py", line 426 in _run
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 763 in run
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 810 in __bootstrap_inner
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 783 in __bootstrap
 
Thread 0x00007f8f03326700:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 202 in accept
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/impl/tcpros_base.py", line 153 in run
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 763 in run
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 810 in __bootstrap_inner
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 783 in __bootstrap
 
Thread 0x00007f8f03d73700:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 358 in wait
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/impl/registration.py", line 297 in run
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/impl/registration.py", line 275 in start
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 763 in run
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 810 in __bootstrap_inner
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 783 in __bootstrap
 
Thread 0x00007f8f04574700:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 155 in _eintr_retry
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 236 in serve_forever
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosgraph/xmlrpc.py", line 284 in _run
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosgraph/xmlrpc.py", line 212 in run
 
Current thread 0x00007f8f1bea1740:
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sensor_msgs/msg/_Image.py", line 145 in serialize
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/msg.py", line 152 in serialize_message
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/topics.py", line 1018 in publish
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/topics.py", line 834 in publish
  File "VideoPublisher.py", line 66 in <module>
```

I would really appreciate if someone takes a look at my problem!
Feel free to ask questions, i had quite some trouble to conclude 4 hours of work in an appropriate way.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/203846/python-rospy-script-doesn%27t-end-running/) by [Holzroller](https://answers.ros.org/users/21083/holzroller/) on ROS Answers with karma: 62 on 2015-02-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You are not using `rospy.is_shutdown()` correctly. Try moving it into the condition of the while-loop. Compare with the example in the tutorial at http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28python%29

---

Originally posted by [slivingston](https://answers.ros.org/users/829/slivingston/) with karma: 254 on 2015-02-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Holzroller](https://answers.ros.org/users/21083/holzroller/) on 2015-02-28**:
oh i see. so i implemented it this way : while cam.isOpened() and not rospy.is_shutdown(): ... and it is working! so if i press ctrl-c now, rospy gets shutdown? Or what does trigger the script to close the ros node?

**Comment by [slivingston](https://answers.ros.org/users/829/slivingston/) on 2015-02-28**:
Yes, by default Ctrl-C causes an interruption signal (`SIGINT`) that is caught by rospy, which then starts a shutdown procedure. You can use different signal handlers or add hooks if you want. Consult http://wiki.ros.org/rospy/Overview/Initialization%20and%20Shutdown